# Unable to create UDA

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and I am using Cassandra 3.10 and when I am going to create a UDA I get the following errors

`OperationTimedOut: errors={'x.x.x.x'}: 'Request timed out while waiting for schema agreement. See session.execute[_async](timeout) and Cluster.max_schema_agree ent_wait.'},last_host=x.x.x.x`

`Warning: schema version mismatch detected; check the schema versions of your nodes in system.local and system.peers`

The UDA that I am creating is

```
CREATE FUNCTION state_group_and_total( state map<text, int>, type text, amount int )
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
RETURNS map<text, int>
LANGUAGE java AS '
Integer count = (Integer) state.get(type);  if (count == null) count = amount; else count = count + amount; state.put(type, count); return state; ' ;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE group_and_total(text, int) 
SFUNC state_group_and_total 
STYPE map<text, int> 
INITCOND {};
```

Comment: From the error. it seems there is multiple version of cassandra is running on your cluster or multiple cf ids existing for one table. please check

Comment: side note: I recommend updating to 3.11, 3.10 had some issues.

Comment: `nodetool describecluster` show any disagreements?